# extract video links in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a app that use a webview to browse pages.

Is there a way to extract the mp4 video links from the pages I browse in webview?

Can I override any method to make webview to return the video links?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, access the HTML content and parse it. No, you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your responso.Do you thnking this app parse html pages too? or have another tehniq? It do good job :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.broloader.android.app&hl=en

Comment: You need a screen scraper. Python's BeautifulSoup works beautifully, but not for Java. I've not tried it but have heard that this scraper (http://jsoup.org/) works well for Java/Android, and indeed their coding samples look easy.